# Android: ListView child duplicates data

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

I am creating a ListView which will consists of three child's. The ListView height and the child height are set same so that only one child visible at a time. I am inflating the child with a layout file which has only one LinearLayout in it. In the adapter class I am adding some views to the LinearLayout dynamically. Now the problem I face is when I scroll the ListView, the data of first child is displaying in the other two child's. Here is my adapter class:

```
public class cListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private List<List<Date>> list;
private Context context;
public cListAdapter(Activity activity, List<List<Date>> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = activity;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public List<Date> getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private static class ViewHolder{
    LinearLayout monthContainer;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view.setTag( holder );
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    holder.monthContainer = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.month);
    List<Date> dates = getItem(position);
    Log.d("Position",""+position);
    Log.d("Dates",""+dates);
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.setTime(dates.get(0));
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    Log.d("Day",""+day);
    int i = 0;
    while( i < dates.size() ){
        LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(context);
        row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            Button b = new Button(context);
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day_bg);
            b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
            if(j<(day-1)) {
                b.setText("");
                row.addView(b);

            }else if(i < dates.size()) {
                b.setText(""+(i+1));
                row.addView(b);
                i++;
                day=0;
            }else{
                b.setText("");
                row.addView(b);
            }

        }
        holder.monthContainer.addView(row);
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using the view recycling that happens in a ListView correctly. Since you will add different data on every item, I suggest you remove all existing data from your monthContainer before adding the new rows. I have provided you with the code below.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View view = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;
if(convertView == null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.monthContainer = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.month);
    view.setTag( holder );
}else{
    holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
}

holder.monthContainer.removeAllViews();
List<Date> dates = getItem(position);
Log.d("Position",""+position);
Log.d("Dates",""+dates);
Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
c.setTime(dates.get(0));
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
Log.d("Day",""+day);
int i = 0;
while( i < dates.size() ){
    LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(context);
    row.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

    for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        Button b = new Button(context);
        b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.day_bg);
        b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        if(j<(day-1)) {
            b.setText("");
            row.addView(b);

        }else if(i < dates.size()) {
            b.setText(""+(i+1));
            row.addView(b);
            i++;
            day=0;
        }else{
            b.setText("");
            row.addView(b);
        }

    }
    holder.monthContainer.addView(row);
}

return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is the child view? you should be using expandable adapter if you need child views and set count to 1, and load data. Adding dynamic layout view inside a listview to a holder is tricky. A screenshot of what you currently have would be helpful